# Why would HTML show up in view:source but not be displayed or rendered on the page?

Tags: html, browser, firebug, developer-tools

What would cause an HTML table and form (viewable in `view:source`) not to render or appear on the page?

It also does not appear in Chrome's Developer Tools console or Firebug console.

I have been trying to figure this out all day and searching is not helping.

Comment: It would be really helpful to have some code to look at.

Comment: Is the content dynamically loaded, with like PHP or ASP? Is the file uploaded to the server? Are you looking at the right file?

Comment: The file is on a development server. We're setting up a webstore to replace an existing one. The page is a template file processed with server-side javascript for tag-replacement, etc... (bleh). I work with HTML all the time but I'm stumped on this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any changes from the raw html you see in view source to the rendered DOM in the browser is caused by JavaScript.

There must be some code on that page that is removing your table.

Can you please provide some code examples of scripts that are on the page and that you are including?

Comment: Thanks, there is so much javascript included in files and script tags, I wouldn't even know where to start. I'll try to narrow it down to what I think would be the most likely culprits and see what/if I can post something. The developers that were hired made quite a mess of things (although the store software itself is quite crazy, imo). The page (mostly) worked, but was incredibly ugly. I'm trying to make it somewhat presentable...

Comment: You can help speed up your search by looking for the table's Id and Classes using a "Find in all files" in your text editor or using a free program like Windows Grep (or just grep on linux).

Comment: A lot of the javascript files were being provided and hosted by the webstore software. Anyways, I basically started the product templates from scratch and everything is working decently well after a lot of work. Still stumped why it wouldn't work before, but agree with you it must have been some javascript somewhere, but I am also not surprised as working with Netsuite is full of wtf moments.